# How to render if only received props in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

PropTable should render only if  receives props from other component

```
const PropTable = (props) => {
  const { availableProp } = props;
...
return(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'd get your job done

```js
const PropTable = (props) => {
  const { availableProp } = props;
...
return availableProp ? (...) : null
}
```